# how call a function from anonymous one?

Tags: powershell

I have this script below and somehow cannot call function from this anonymous one.
I need to call mail function to send notification on this event.

```
function test
{
    Write-Host "send email" 
}

$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" 
    test
    }

  $folder = 'C:\temp'
    $filter = '*.*'                             
    $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true        
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
    }
    $onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -  Action         $action
```

Event is caught, write-host writes fine but test function is not called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not exactly an issue of calling a function from an "anonymous one" ( called a scriptblock).

What is happening here is that when you specify an action to `Register-ObjectEvent`, it sets up a job and sends the action as the command for the job. When the event occurs and the job runs, it has no clue what the test function is.

If you actually do `Get-Job` and see the job, you will see that it has failed. Easiest solution is to inline the code. Or have the function in your session, by either defining it with `global` scope:

```
function global:test
{
    Write-Host "send email" 
}
```

or manually just defining it in you console or adding it to your profile.

Alternatively, you can add the function to a script, say `test.ps1`, dot source it in your `$action`  - `. path\to\test.ps1` and then call `test`:

```
$action = {
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
. c:\test.ps1
test
}
```

Comment: thanks guys, I suspected scoping here but didn't know what is the way out in powershell. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scoping issue. Once the event is fired, the script is no longer in scope and so it can't see the function `test`. There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. Put test in global scope:

   function global:test
   {
       Write-Host "send email" 
   }
2. Dot-Source the script, so that test will be injected into the parent scope:

   . .\yourScript.ps1

Comment: Um, dot sourcing the same script will run the script, along with the other commands.

Comment: @manojlds: I didn't mean for the script to dot-source itself, but to dot-source it when it is originally invoked.